# BottomNavigationView design with XML *no programmatically

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationbar

Good day. How can I change icon and text color(active and inactive), using XML?

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    />
```

Comment: have you tried with `app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"` ?

Comment: +, I want to change icon color only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_state_list"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_state_list"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_category" />
```

Inside your `drawable` create `color` folder and there put `nav_state_list`  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/yourColor" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/yourColor" android:state_checked="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the text add these 2 lines to yout BottomNavigationView:

```
app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/tabbar_text_active"
app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/tabbar_text_inactive"
```

and create style for them in your `style.xml`

```
<style name="tabbar_text_active" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryLight</item>
</style>

<style name="tabbar_text_inactive" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textLight</item>
</style>
```

For icon

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
```

With a drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/primaryLight" />
   <item android:color="@color/textLight" />
</selector>
```