# How to change selected item background color in bottomnaviagtion view

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the background color of selected item in navigation view.

I have tried with selector color file and also drawable but nothing is working..
when i run all the time exception at itemBackground attribute..

**background_color_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

**Bottom Navigation**
line no 49 is (app:itemBackground)

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_bottom_navigation"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_bottom_navigation"
        app:itemBackground="@color/background_color_tab"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/icon_size"
        app:elevation="5dp">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

**ERROR**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.ccms/com.example.ccms.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML
>   file line #49: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: try adding "android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background color change in BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421553/background-color-change-in-bottomnavigationview)

Comment: First migrate to androidX then follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974956/7254873

Answer (score 1):

you can not set color resource in `app:itemBackground` you must have to set drawable resource in this property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer it's really helpful for a beginner like me..!!